# WebRTC ability to broadcast one local video stream to a peer but receive/display multiple video streams from several remote peers?

Tags: webrtc

Basically I have a media server where I have multiple clients in a conference sending one stream and receiving multiple streams (the media server does not mix the streams to make it 1:1).  I have it such that WebRTC/Chrome attaches and can exchange streams in a 1:1 scenario but am unclear if/how to do 1:N with WebRTC.  To reiterate, it's not peer-to-peer-X-N, it's send one, receive many.  Any thoughts?  Thanks.

Comment: Are you meant something like this? https://googledrive.com/host/0B6GWd_dUUTT8RzVSRVU2MlIxcm8/RTCMultiConnection-v1.1/multi-session-establishment.html

Comment: I have a need for a single bi-directional audio stream, a single video broadcast stream, and multiple video receive streams.  It's not clear what you've done allows that but it looks close/interesting and I'll take a closer look at it, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spec allows for receiving (and sending) multiple streams in a single RTCPeerConnection.  However, the current implementations in Chrome (I believe) and Firefox do not enable that yet.  You can receive mutliple RTCPeerConnections, so a possible workaround is for you to have multiple RTCPeerConnections to the server, one of which is sending, and the others of which are receive-only (there are constraints to createOffer() to (not) offer to receive audio and video without adding a MediaStream).

This would work similarly to the spec, except you'd be responsible for managing N RTCPeerConnections.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm currently on the path of multiple RTCPeerConnections to the server (also looking forward to ice-lite support to reduce startup time).  I'm in the middle of development on this approach, which is one RTCPC for the bidirectional audio (on HTML audio element, specifying no video), one RTCPC for video send (specifying no audio), and multiple RTCPCs for video receive (specifying no audio).  I'm having a hard time finding docs on the MediaConstraints... sounds like you're suggesting some send-only or receive-only type constraints... can you point me the right direction?

Comment: Spent the day coding away on this and it appears to be working... two receive-only streams with two peer connections streaming at once, simultaneous with bidirectional audio.  No need for any additional media constraints at this point.  Last item will be doing the send-only stream.

Comment: Forgot to follow up on this... but the one send-only stream is fine too.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to need a peer 2 peer implementation of webRTC . I am not sure but you should check these:

https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/03/webrtc-data-channels-for-great-multiplayer/

https://github.com/js-platform/p2p

Comment: I'm currently using RTCPeerConnection (it gathers the ICE candidates, negotiates with server, gets a remote stream, etc.) but I'm using the IP/Port provided via SDP for both sourcing the local stream as well as receiving the remote stream.  Perhaps you're suggesting I don't need to add in the local stream and it can be a "remote only" connection?

Comment: It seems thats how its seems to be done in the blog however the server is just acting as a broker. However I have not done this and actually like to know more if you implement something

Comment: FYI I'm having some success with this path... 2 video peer connections both doing receive-only, along with 1 bidirectional audio peer connection.  Only remaining item is 1 video peer connection for send-only.